# Multiple dependencies error during build on iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm trying to build my nativescript app on iOS.
I have brand new MacMini with fresh system and all stuff like xcode, etc.
My app builds without any warnings on android - not checked android build on Mac.

When i try to run my app on emulator i have an error saying:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `Socket.IO-Client-Swift` in `Podfile`:
- Socket.IO-Client-Swift (from `https://github.com/triniwiz/socket.io-client-swift.git`)
- Socket.IO-Client-Swift (~> 12.1.3)
'pod install' command failed.
```

Tried to remove one of the dependency from pod file but without any luck - it brings back during build.

What should i do?

Comment: Are you using multiple plugins those use same POD but different versions? If that's the case you should find out which version of library works for both of your plugins and then override the versions in your app specific POD file.

Comment: @Manoj how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

After updating my dependencies, I also ran into an issue with Cocopods, although, not exactly the same. In my case, running `pod repo update` from within `platforms/ios` solved my problem. In short, there had been updates that my local pod spec repo wasn't aware of and it was getting "confused". I'm not sure if this will ultimately solve your specific problem, but it's fairly quick to do and, at least, won't hurt anything.

Good luck!